# I can not install packages with PIP from Jenkins and Virtualenv

Tags: python, jenkins, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying execute this script from Jenkins:

```
#!/bin/sh
source /home/user/venv/venv3/bin/activate  
cd /home/user/project/
pip install -r requeriments.txt     
python manage.py migrate               
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

But I keep having issues installing some package with pip:

```
error: could not create '/home/user/venv/venv3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/markdown': Permission denied
```

I created the virtualenv with my user (not sudo) and python3.

Comment: Is jenkins running as your user?

Comment: No, I can run the script as my user from Jenkins?, sorry, I'm still a noob in Jenkins :)

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins runs as the "jenkins" user. That user almost certainly doesn't have write access to your user's directories. You'd have to create the virtualenv and project directory in jenkins' own home dir (`/var/lib/jenkins`).

To debug it, you could run the script by hand as the jenkins user. So not from within jenkins, but on the command line after doing `sudo su jenkins`. You'll see the same error.